# How to improve assembly loading for application with many assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, clr

We have .net 4.8 WPF desktop application with over 300+ assemblies to load. When started for the first time after reboot it takes ~10 sec more to start than if it was started before that. I suspect that somehow Windows OS cache loaded assemblies and when started again after small amount of time it took less time to read from the hard disk. We had small console app that loads all the assemblies in the app directory and we can see that the cold starts are indeed ~10 sec slower because of the assembly file loads.

To improve the startup we currently use ngen and our assemblies and don't have strong names (I know that make loading of the assemblies even worse)

I can't find any information what exactly makes hot starts faster. Also I need to know if there is a way to speed up Assembly.Load somehow other than having all the code in one big assembly.

Comment: ILMerge maybe? i.e. to *turn* those assemblies into one?

Comment: You might want to profile what you are actually doing on startup. Assemblies are loaded on demand, so one approach is to try to do less at startup, try to reduce the amount of code that needs to be jitted. Also, to many small projects can impact both compilation and startup performance. It is somewhat common for developers to add a new project when writing some new component, without really thinking if there are good reasons to put the component in a separate project.

Comment: It is notable how questions about cold start perf stopped being asked at SO after SSDs became common.  A cheap and simple fix.